# Number of subgraphs with $n$ vertices of a (vertex labelled) complete graph $K_n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

If $K_n$ is a (vertex  labelled) complete graph with $n$ vertices and $S$ is the set of all subgraphs of $K_n$, then the formula for cardinality of $S$ is given by

> $|S|=1+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}\times 2+\binom{n}{3}\times 2^3+\binom{n}{4}\times 2^6+...+\binom{n}{n}\times 2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}.$

If a subset $S'$ of $S$ is the set of only all those subgraphs of $K_n$ whose vertex sets are $V(K_n)$ i.e., each graph in $S'$ has $n$ vertices, then what is the cardinality of $S'$?

Comment: Now it's just a matter of which subsets of the edges are included.  How many subsets has the edge set?

Comment: The expression of $|S|$ should have $2$ attached to $\binom n2$. What do you think the last term of this sum corresponds to??

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks for the corrections. Is the last term corresponds to the powerset of the edges of $K_n$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There are $\binom n2=\frac{n(n-1)}2$ edges.

Comment: The last term corresponds to selecting all $n$ of the vertices for the subgraph. As saulspatz mentioned, now we have $\binom n2$ edges to choose from, we can select a subset of the edges in $|\mathcal P(E)|=2^{\binom n2}$ ways.

Comment: Thank you. It works.